# Pushing Data Into My Redux State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Right now I am mapping over an array with an endpoint to my API. From there I am taking every link and calling a get request on each thing I map over. My issue is that I am not able to save everything into my redux state. I have tried using concat and push to take everything and put it all in one array in my redux state.

MomentContent.js:

```
componentDidMount () {

      this.props.photos.map(photo => {
        this.props.fetchPhoto(this.props.token, photo)}
      )
    }
```

index.js (actions):

```
export const fetchPhoto = (token, photo) => dispatch => {
  console.log('right token')
  console.log(token);
  fetch(photo, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Token ${token}`,
    }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(parsedRes => {
    console.log('photo data')
    console.log(parsedRes)
    dispatch(getPhoto(parsedRes))
  })
}

export const getPhoto = (photo) => {
  console.log('RES')
  console.log(photo)
  return {
    type: GET_PHOTO,
    photo: photo
  }
}
```

When I use concat (reducer):

```
import {
  GET_PHOTO
} from '../actions';

const initialState = {
  photo: []
}

const photoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_PHOTO:
      return {
        ...state,
        photo: initialState.photo.concat([action.photo])
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default photoReducer
```

[image]

When I use push (reducer):

```
import {
  GET_PHOTO
} from '../actions';

const initialState = {
  photo: []
}

const photoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_PHOTO:
      return {
        ...state,
        photo: initialState.photo.push([action.photo])
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default photoReducer
```

[image]

UPDATE (another issue):

I was able to get it to work with :

```
return {
        ...state,
        photo: [...state.photo, action.photo]
      }
```

The issue now is that every time I refresh the same data is pushed again, so everything multiplies. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to merge your **`updatedState`** and not **`initialState`** to the reducer in order to update

Either using **concat**:

```
return {
  ...state,
  photo: state.photo.concat([action.photo])
}
```

or **using spread operator**

```
return {
  ...state,
  photo: [...state.photo, action.photo]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the push does not work correctly in redux, the ideal is to use the spread operator to concatenate the arrays

```
return {
     ... state,
     photo: [... initialState.photo, action.photo]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `action.photo` is an array, no need to wrap it with additional `[]`.

If you want the newly fetched photo array to combined with existing photo array in the Redux state, use `state.photo.push` instead of `initialState.photo.push`.

```
case GET_PHOTO:
      return {
        ...state,
        photo: state.photo.push(action.photo)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript push method on array return you the new size of the array and hence it won't work correctly.

what you need is to use `concat` or `spread-syntax`

```
case GET_PHOTO:
  return {
    ...state,
    photo: initialState.photo.concat([action.photo])
  }
```

or

```
case GET_PHOTO:
  return {
    ...state,
    photo: [...initialState.photo, action.photo]
  }
```